# Substring of column name in Copy Activity in ADF v2

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a way in the V2 Copy Activity to operate upon one of the input columns (of type string) with an expression? Before I load rows to the destination, I need to limit the number of characters in the column.

My hope was to simply switch from something like this:

```
"ColumnMappings": "inColumn: outColumn"
```

to something like this:

```
"ColumnMappings": "@substring(inColumn, 1, 300): outColumn"
```

If anyone can point me to where I can read-up on where & when string expressions can be used, I could use the guidance.

Comment: I did try changing the syntax for "columnMappings" to use the "value"/"type" format shown here (to no avail): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828502/adf-v2-error-the-string-character-at-position-is-not-expected/47900984#47900984

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't have a SQL Source, but your destination is a SQL sink, you can use a Stored Procedure to insert your data into the final table. That way, you can define these kinds of transformations in the stored procedure. I don't think the Data Factory can handle these kinds of activities, it is more intended as an orchestrator.

Have a look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server#invoke-stored-procedure-from-sql-sink

Comment: I don't think that I gave this enough consideration initially because I suffered for too long under the Azure SQL Warehouse (the sink) caps of varchar(8000) & nvarchar(4000). Since updates have removed those caps, you're right...the easiest thing is to let the full string in to unbounded columns, and then truncate them down to reasonable size via stored proc. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is the official documentation on expressions and functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions

And this is the documentation on mappings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping

Also remember that if you are using a defined query in the copy activity, you can use sql functions like CAST([fieldName] as varchar(300)) to limit the amount of characters on a particular field.

Hope this helped!

Comment: CAST & CONVERT would be perfect, but I haven't found a way to use them that works with an Azure Table Storage source.

Comment: My other idea (that I'm still hoping might exist) would be to find a setting that tells the target table to ignore truncation errors (similar to SSIS). Otherwise, I think that I'm going to have to learn how to write a transformation step in Data Factory. Thanks!